# make different list based on number of elements in list of lists

Tags: python, list, dataframe

I want to generate different lists from a list of lists. See the example

```
[['this', "isn't", 'working'], ['working', 'great'], ["isn't", 'working'], ['and'], ['great'], ['working', 'this', "isn't"]]
```

it should be like

```
list1 = [['and'], ['great']]
list2 = [['working', 'great'], ["isn't", 'working']]
list3 = [['this', "isn't", 'working'],['working', 'this', "isn't"]]
like wise...list4 having 4 elements and so on.
```

and then convert them into a data-frame. But for this time being, I want to create lists based on the elements. It would be a help if some ideas can be suggested. For the example purpose, a small list is shown in the example, it would be a big list so an efficient technique is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: @yatu, Yes the answer is somewhat useful but still needed some more clarity I needed. I have mentioned this in the comments on your answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is defining a `defaultdict`, and inserting elements with keys corresponding to the sublists' length, and keep the `dict.values` `sorted` by key:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

for subl in l:
    d[len(subl)].append(subl)

out = [d[i] for i in sorted(d)]
```

---

```
print(out)

[[['and'], ['great']],
 [['working', 'great'], ["isn't", 'working']],
 [['this', "isn't", 'working'], ['working', 'this', "isn't"]]]
```